# Solve the recurrence relation $a_n =1.04*a_{n−1}+100, a_0 =0$

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

How do I do this? We're currently learning how to solve nonhomogeneous recurrence relations.

Comment: is it $a_{n-1}$?

Comment: It is! Sorry, I will edit that in.

Comment: Duplicate of [Solving a non-homogenous linear recurrence relation with initial conditions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2158577/solving-a-non-homogenous-linear-recurrence-relation-with-initial-conditions)

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

1. Shift the term with $a_{n - 1}$ to the left.
2. Divide throughout by $1.04^n$.
3. Do a summation on both sides.
4. LHS telescopes and almost everything is cancelled out.
5. RHS is just a geometric series.